# String in a Box representation makes a subtle error

Tags: functions, function-construction, string-manipulation, cells, printing

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], 
  Inset[Style["ABC", FontSize -> 30], {0.5, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 200]

QWE = "ABC"; 
GraphicsBox[{CircleBox[{0, 0}], 
     InsetBox[StyleBox[QWE, FontSize -> 30], {0.5, 0}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 200] // BoxData // Cell // CellPrint

GraphicsBox[{CircleBox[{0, 0}], 
     InsetBox[StyleBox["ABC", FontSize -> 30], {0.5, 0}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 200] // BoxData // Cell // CellPrint

GraphicsBox[{CircleBox[{0, 0}], 
   InsetBox[StyleBox[ToString[ABC], FontSize -> 30], {0.5, 0}]}, 
  ImageSize -> 200] // BoxData // Cell // CellPrint
```

Above are 4 codes.
1st, 2nd, 3rd works but 4th codes not works as expected.
I don't know why 4th-code made an error.

Also, can you construct function `SomeExcellentFunction`, so that

```
GraphicsBox[{CircleBox[{0, 0}], 
       InsetBox[StyleBox[SomeExcellentFunction[ABC], FontSize -> 30], {0.5, 0}]}, 
      ImageSize -> 200] // BoxData // Cell // CellPrint
```

works correctly ?

I add a screenshot for 1st to 4th code, in order.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

+-+-+-+ added -+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

You can further try

```
GraphicsBox[{CircleBox[{0, 0}], 
     InsetBox[StyleBox[Identity["ABC"], FontSize -> 30], {0.5, 0}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 200] // BoxData // Cell // CellPrint
```

It doesn't works surprisingly.
An exceptional phenomenon for `Identity`.

Comment: It's probably best to post answers in the answers section, not the question body.  IMO.

Comment: The help says that "StyleBox" takes boxes as input. But you give a string.

Answer (score 1):

So far I've used `RowBox`, `GridBox`, `AdjustmentBox` mostly.

But

```
{RowBox, GridBox, AdjustmentBox, GraphicsBox, InsetBox} // 
  Attributes // TableForm[#, TableDepth -> 1] &
```

gives

```
{Protected}
{Protected,ReadProtected}
{Protected,ReadProtected}
{HoldAll,Protected,ReadProtected}
{HoldAll,Protected,ReadProtected}
```

Unlike `RowBox`, `GridBox`, `AdjustmentBox`, check that
`GraphicsBox`, `InsetBox` has `HoldAll` attribute.

It seems that I can temporarily remove that attribute.

Finally I found the solution on my own.
The solution is

```
graphicsbox[x__]:=GraphicsBox[x]  
insetbox[x__]:=InsetBox[x]
```

Then, use `graphicsbox` and `insetbox` instead of `GraphicsBox` and `InsetBox`.